# Using 'just like' in a sentence with subject + object

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I always use "just like" + noun, plus also see some sentences using this form with subject + object.

I have not seen any particular English lessons for this usage, could someone explain me how I can use "just like" in a different situation. For example, is the sentence below are correct?

> You can find the proper description on the prospectus of the machine **just like** everyone does.

I want to emphasis that everyone finds clear information in this prospectus before running the machine.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, 'just like' is similar in meaning to 'in the same way'. I should also note that is it quite informal, so using it with all those big words in the sentence makes it seem unprofessional. Which is the goal, right?

In response to your request, you can add emphasis by using the phrase 'anyone and everyone':

> Anyone and everyone can find the proper description on the prospectus of the machine.